# Show map of non-joining rows in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, join, reverse

I have three tables

#### permissions

```
id | name
 1 | do.this
 2 | do.that
 3 | dont.this
 4 | dont.that
 5 | neither.this
 6 | both.that
```

#### roles

```
id | name
 1 | doer
 2 | donter
```

#### permission_role

```
permission_id | role_id
            1 | 1
            2 | 1
            6 | 1
            3 | 2
            4 | 2
            6 | 2
```

So with the below query we can get all roles a user has like so

```
permission_id | permission_name | role_id | role_name
            1 | do.this         |       1 | doer
            2 | do.that         |       1 | doer
            6 | both.that       |       1 | doer
            3 | dont.this       |       2 | donter
            4 | dont.that       |       2 | donter
            6 | both.that       |       2 | donter
```

#### query

```
SELECT 
p.id AS permission_id, p.name AS permission_name, 
r.id AS role_id, r.name AS role_name FROM permission_role pr 
JOIN permissions p ON pr.`permission_id` = p.id
JOIN roles r ON pr.`role_id` = r.id;
```

#### The question

What I am wondering is, how can we reverse this query, so create a result set listing all the permissions the roles *don't* have like so:

```
permission_id | permission_name | role_id | role_name
            3 | dont.this       |       1 | doer
            4 | dont.that       |       1 | doer
            5 | neither.this    |       1 | doer
            1 | do.this         |       2 | donter
            2 | do.that         |       2 | donter
            5 | neither.this    |       2 | donter
```

Comment: sidenote... Based on your joining table name and foreign key names, it would be more consistent to name your tables the singular 'permission' and 'role'.  That way other people/tools querying don't have to know conversion between plural to singluar.  think a table name people and mice, your linking table would be mouse_person and your foreign keys would be mouse_id, person_id

Comment: Blame laravels ORM.  This is the convention there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The logic for this type of query starts with generating all combinations of roles and permissions and then removing the ones that exist (using `left outer join`).

```
select p.id as permission_id, p.name as permission_name,
       r.id as role_id, r.name as role_name
from roles r cross join
     permissions p left outer join
     permission_role pr
     on pr.permission_id = p.id and
        pr.role_id = r.id
where pr.role_id is null;
```